# would vs would have been

Tags: tense, will-would

> In the Soviet Union, bribing government-employed sales clerks to avoid
> standing in line for scarce items, or just to find out when a shipment
> of oranges or imported Western shoes **would be** on sale, was established
> practice.

Should it be "would have been" here instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's correct as is.

It's the past form of "will be". "Would have been" is unreal past. This is not unreal.